# How to use hibernate for tables that are not linked at DB Level?

Tags: database, hibernate, hql

I'm new to hibernate. I have a requirement to use hibernate for fetching records from one of our legacy database (seems the DB does not have proper FK relationships defined).

```
public class Class1 {

    @Id
    int index;
    @ManyToOne
    private Class2 class2;
        ....
        ....

}


public class Class2 {
    ...

    private Collection<Class1> class1;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="index")
    public Collection<Class1> getClass1() {
        return class1;
    }
    public void setClass1(Collection<Class1> class1) {
        this.class1= class1;
    }
}
```

My requirement is to fetch object as a collection.

```
Object1 of Class2 ->  Object1 of Class 1
                      Object2 of class 1
                      Object3 of class 1

Object1 of Class2 ->  Object4 of Class 1
                      Object5 of class 1
                      Object6 of class 1

Object1 of Class2 ->  Object7 of Class 1
                      Object8 of class 1
                      Object9 of class 1
```

I have common tables in the database eventhough FK relationship not specified.

I'm just wondering if I can use hibernate relationships (like @Onetomany) for entities whose tables correspondent do not have link at database level

Answer (score 0):

If your mapping corresponds to the structure of the database tables, everything will work as expectd. The fact that there exist a foreign key constraint or not doesn't matter.

Your mapping is wrong though. In a bidirectional OneToMany association, the *one* side must be marked as the inverse side of the *many* side using the `mappedBy` attribute. See [the hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#collections-bidirectional) for how to map bidirectional associations.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I got it now. Now I have a different error. Hibernate sql contains wrong coloumn name and it tries to fetch that coloumn. Example , YYY_.xxxx_Field as ABC5_5_1_ ; here i donot have a field named xxxx_Field in YYY table,but i have something named Field in my YYY table. Why hibernate query has this non-existing coloumn name. Any idea?

Comment: Because you didn't specify how the xxxx_Field of your entity was mapped to the tabled. Use the @Column annotation (if it's a basic field and not an association) to specify which column corresponds to the field.

Comment: I have another quick question. Is it mandatory to have @ManyToOne for the second entity if I use @OneToMany? Any examples?

Comment: No, it's not. This would be a unidirectional OneToMany association, which is also described in the hibernate documentation.